# Drupal view sing a different template on every page load

Tags: view, twig, drupal-8

I have a view

It used to be called 'page_1'
It is now called 'c_page'

I have created a template called

'node--view--branch-list--c-page.html' to render this view

This worked perfectly for many weeks. Until now

Sometimes when i load a page created by this view it is very very glitched.
And sometimes when i load a page created by this view it is fine.

After much investigating i discovered that this is happening because the template suggestions are different on each page load

sometimes the first two template suggestions are

* node--view--branch-list--page-1.html.twig
   x node--view--branch-list.html.twig

and sometimes they are

* node--view--branch-list--c-page.html.twig
   x node--view--branch-list.html.twig

If 'node--view--branch-list--c-page.html' is in the list it works fine

If 'node--view--branch-list--page-1.html.twig' is in the list it uses 'node--view--branch-list.html.twig' because ' node--view--branch-list--page-1.html.twig' does not exist/

Sometimes the exact same page (the view generates many pages) is fine sometimes it isnt.
This happens on multiple different servers.
Clearing the drupal cache makes no difference
Turning the view cache off makes no difference.

What could be causing this

Answer (score 0):

I guess, probably there is a `preprocess_node` or `theme_suggestions` function that generates the theme suggestion.

Please check your `.theme` file inside of your theme folder.